# Find the first missing number in a sequence of numbers

Tags: php, while-loop

It's the second day I try to find a solution for this problem.

I have an array.

```
$datas;

$datas[0]; // 8000
$datas[1]; // 8001
$datas[2]; // 8003
$datas[3]; // 8004
```

I have to find the first missing number starting from 8000 in this case it's 8002.

My idea is to do somethig like this:

`$datas[0] +1 = $datas[1]`

if it's true port it's not free and I have to check the next one, if it's false it's the first free number.

I know it's not a correct syntax but I have some problems writing it in the right way.

Comment: Have you tried anything on your own? Besides the code that obviously does not work.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-missing-number/ there is no example for PHP but they provided basic logic

Comment: Did you give up?

Answer (score 2):

You can use array_diff to find the missing value.
I create a new array with values from min of $datas to max of $datas to compare against.
The return is what is missing.

```
$arr = range(min($datas),max($datas));

Var_dump(min(array_diff($arr,$datas)));
```

https://3v4l.org/ZmLAU

Can be a one liner too:

```
Var_dump(min(array_diff(range(min($datas),max($datas)), $datas)));
```

Comment: Good one but this can return multiple values not just the lowest.

Comment: @AbraCadaver true.. but min() of return is the lowest then.

Comment: Also could do array_values and pick out key 0 if its there, I was about to post this, too late. plus one

Comment: Thanks, yeah array_values work or just `$arr[0]` since the return array is not associative

Answer (score 1):

Sort from lowest to highest (if not already sorted) and then increment from the lowest and check if it is in the array:

```
sort($datas); 
for($i=reset($datas); in_array($i, $datas); $i++);
echo $i;
```

`reset` gets the first number, in this case 8000 to start and the `in_array` condition terminates the loop when `$i` is not in the array.

Comment: Thant workes like a charm, it tooks me a bit tu understand it because I'm really at the beginning with programming but it works really fine.

Answer (score 0):

something like this should work

```
for($i=0;$i<count($datas);$i++){
  if($datas[$i] + 1 != $datas[$i+1]){
    echo($datas[$i] + 1 .' IS the missing number');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With something like this, it's pretty simple to just iterate through the array with a foreach loop.

```
foreach ($datas as $key=>$val) { 
  if ( $val +1 != $datas[$key+1] ) { 
    echo $val+1; // this is the first free value in the sequence
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

function get($data) {
    sort($data);
    $i = 0;
    while($i < count($data) - 2) {
        if ($data[$i+1] - $data[$i] != 1) return $data[$i] + 1;
        $i++;
    }

    return $data[count($data)-1] + 1;
}

echo get([ 8000, 8001, 8003, 8004,]);
echo get([ 8000, 8001, 8002, 8003, 8004,]);
```